# Simplifying $\sec^2 x-\tan^2 x$

Tags: trigonometry

> How do I simplify this expression?
>   $$\sec^2 x-\tan^2 x$$

I am trying to solve this problem and I am stuck because $\sec^2 x$ is a reciprocal of cosine and $\tan^2 x$ is a function of $\sin(x)/\cos(x)$.

How would I subtract this? I don't see anything I can cancel out.

Comment: $\sec^2 x - \tan^2x = \frac {1}{\cos^2 x} - \frac {\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x}$

Answer (score 1):

If you know the identity $\sec^2x=1+\tan^2x$, then this easily simplifies to:
$$\sec^2 x-\tan^2 x$$
$$=(1+\tan^2x)-\tan^2x$$
$$=1$$
But in your question you mentioned reciprocals, so I am assuming you can't use the above identity. In that case, you can do the following:

Writing $\sec^2x\; \text{as}\; \frac{1}{\cos^2x}$ and $\tan^2x$ as $\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}$:
$$\sec^2 x-\tan^2 x$$
$$=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}-\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}$$
Using the common denominator:
$$=\frac{1-\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}$$
$$ $$
Using $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1\implies\cos^2x=1-\sin^2x$:
$$ $$
$$=\frac{\cos^2x}{\cos^2x}$$
$$=1$$

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Take $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ and divide both sides by $\cos^2 x$ to get a relationship between $\sec^2 x$ and $\tan^2 x$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** $$\sec^2x-\tan^2x=\frac{1}{\cos^2x}-\frac{\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}=\frac{1-\sin^2x}{\cos^2x}$$
you should also know that $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$